# Powershell Select-String: Get results by named regex group

Tags: powershell

I have this Select-String using a regex containing a named group

```
$m=Select-String -pattern '(?<mylabel>error \d*)' -InputObject 'Some text Error 5 some text'
```

Select-String does its job:

```
PS > $m.Matches.groups


Groups   : {0, mylabel}
Success  : True
Name     : 0
Captures : {0}
Index    : 10
Length   : 7
Value    : Error 5

Success  : True
Name     : mylabel
Captures : {mylabel}
Index    : 10
Length   : 7
Value    : Error 5
```

I can get the value of the matching named group by using the index of the group, no problem:

```
PS > $m.Matches.groups[1].Value
Error 5
```

But I have no success in getting the same result by using the named regex group (mylabel). I found statements like `$m.Matches.groups["mylabel"].Value` but that doesn't work on my machines (W10/W2012, PS 5.1)

Comment: unless you have a need for something special that only `Select-String` can provide, use the vanilla `-match` instead. this `'Some text Error 5 some text' -match '(?<mylabel>error \d*)'` gives this `$Matches.mylabel` with finally gives this `Error 5`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I have a reason to use Select-String. My real world script searches potentially hundreds of log files for errors `Get-ChildItem d:\logs\*.log -recurse | Select-String -pattern '<regex>'`

Comment: the problem was the wrong place for your `Groups` property. [*grin*] use this instead `$m.Matches[0].Groups['mylabel']`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thanks! Big jaw dropper for me is that it is necessary to index into Matches `$m.Matches[0]` here while when using the numerical index of the regex group things works without that.

Comment: you are welcome! the problem was the way that PoSh will give you an array of the properties from a collection when you use `$Collection.PropName` the result can be a tad strange. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Yes, that was the pitfall I fell into :-/

Answer (score 2):

You got one correct answer in the comment above, but here is how to do it without using the 0 match index:

```
$m.Matches.groups | ? { $_.Name -eq 'mylabel' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
```